# Condição para execução de alarmes em Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Ao criar um alarme para Windows Phone 8.0 por meio do seguinte código:

```
Alarm alarm = new Alarm(nome)
{
    BeginTime = dateValue,
    ExpirationTime = dateValue2,
    Content = "Horário!!!",
    RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.Daily,
    };
ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);
```

Gostaria de saber como manipular esse alarme para ser executado com base em uma condição na hora em que deve ser iniciado.

Comment: Poderia exemplificar o que deseja fazer para melhor compreensão? @beatriz

Comment: Bom, eu quero agendar um determinado intervalo de tempo. E se durante esse intervalo de tempo, por exemplo das 12h às 15h, for encontrada uma temperatura adequada(não muito quente)... Eu quero que o alarme dispare, avisando a pessoa que uma temperatura adequada foi encontrada dentro do intervalo de tempo agendado! Compreende?

Comment: Ou seja, eu  vou usar uma condição... Eu quero utilizar o while... Porque o caraa vai agendar uma hora inicial e uma hora final... Ai é o seguinte... Eu quero fazer uma condição assim: enquanto a hora inicial for maior ou igual a hora do celular e  a hora final agendada for menor ou igual a hora do celular... eu quero que fique verificando dentro dessa condição while através de um IF se há a temperatura  adequada ou não...

Comment: Se a temperatura adequada for encontrada eu quero que o alarme dispare avisando que foi encontrada... caso contrario que ele dispare avisando que não foi encontrada... Entendeu?